# Kind signatures and Type families

Tags: haskell, types

I expect

```
type family Rep a
```

and

```
type family Rep :: * -> *
```

to be the same, but it seems there is a difference

```
type family   Rep a
type instance Rep Int  = Char
-- ok

type family   Rep :: * -> *
type instance Rep Int  = Char
-- Expected kind * -> *, but got 'Int' instead
```

Have I simply stumbled over an Haskell extension bug, or is there some point to this behavior?

Comment: The point is type families are not 'type-level functions'. They are 'families of types'. You should view the syntactic similarities between value-level pattern matching and type family instance declarations as a coincidence - the two have entirely different semantics (e.g. try writing the value-level function which matches on the constructor `Left :: a -> Either a b`). You've already witnessed a minimal example of the difference. The 2nd type family is basically just a type synonym, as it can only have a single instance. The 1st is a proper type family.

Comment: I wish I had a simple way of explaining the difference between a 'type-level function' and a 'family of types', but I don't. The difference comes down to the fact that the 1st type family cannot be partially applied (nor can the 2nd, of course, but any use of the 2nd is a saturated application, as it takes 0 arguments) - in other words, the 1st type family doesn't have a kind which can be assigned to it in the Haskell type system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a subtle difference.

Roughly, `type family F a :: *->*` states that, say, `F Int` is an *injective* type constructor like `[]`, `Maybe`. This is exploited by the compiler, which can type check the following code:

```
type family F a :: * -> *

-- these three examples can be removed / changed, if wished
type instance F Int = []
type instance F Char = Maybe
type instance F Bool = (,) String

foo :: (F Int a :~: F Int b) -> (a :~: b)
foo Refl = Refl
```

To type check the above, the compiler exploited the fact that 
`F Int a ~ F Int b` implies `a ~ b`, which follows from injectivity.

Instead, declaring `type family F a b :: *` does not ensure injectivity of `F Int`, since the following becomes legal.

```
type family F a b :: *
type instance F Int a = ()
```